# Inspect element or page source of SOAP UI Browser window

Tags: soapui

I am validating the OAuth functionality within SOAP UI tool and I need to know if we can change the default browser or if not how do we view the page source just like we do it in any other browser ? ( right click isn't an option here ) Image reference below

I couldn't find any references in the SmartBear community

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to **MockServices** with `SoapUI` if I am not wrong?

Comment: Can you see the log statement to which url it is hitting to show the above dark themed page? And you externally hit the same url from the browser where you can do the right click?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the source, and have the URL, you can do this in a Groovy script step in SoapUI:

```
    def pageSource = new URL("https://whatever-you-url-is").getText()
    log.info pageSource
```